# Can not get customer icon to work for GMaps Marker - gmaps4rails

Tags: google-maps, marker, gmaps4rails

I'm using the gmaps4rails gem, and having a hard time getting custom icons or tooltips to work with GMaps Markers. Here is the code I'm using:

```
                    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
                    handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'geolocation'} }, function(){
                    if(navigator.geolocation)
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayOnMap);
                    });


                    function displayOnMap(position){
                    var marker = handler.addMarker(
                    {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude,
                        infowindow: "This is your current location",
                        title:'Your current location'
                     }, 
                     {
                        opacity: 0.6,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        cursor: "crosshair",
                        icon: {URL: "/images/icons/mapmarkers/blue_MarkerA.png"}
                     });

                    handler.map.centerOn(marker);
```

Basically I'm trying to use a blue marker for the customer's current location and show some tooltips. "opacity", "animation", and "cursor" all work fine, but neither "icon" or "title" attributes work.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: iconBase + 'schools_maps.png'
});
```

You need to define icon base first and reference it when you are defining your marker class.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but it did not work. This one seems to be very stubborn. Any other ideas? Thanks